# Multiple Folders in Multiple Media Picker Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to add multiple folders in a Multiple Media Picker but when i'm looping through it i'm only getting a single ID.

[image]

This is the code i'm using to loop through the content:

```
 var tabList = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("containertab").Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse);
```

Is it allowed to add multiple folders in multiple media picker? How can get the ID of each folder?

Comment: It is allowed, try to display the raw field to check you have multiple id's @{
<p>@CurrentPage.containertab</p>
}

Comment: @JanBluemink that works. put it into the answer so I could close this question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is allowed, try to display the raw field to check you have multiple id's 
somethings like `1135,1136`

```
@{
<p>@CurrentPage.containertab</p>
}
```

Simple code example:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentPage.containertab))
{
    foreach (var x in CurrentPage.containertab.ToString().Split(','))
    {
        var media = Umbraco.Media(int.Parse(x));

    }
}
```